# PowerShell Script ErrorActionPreference

Tags: powershell

Why does the try/catch statement in the following code not work when ran as a script from PowerShell?  If I set the $ErrorActionPreference to 'Stop' before running the script, it works as intended, but if it's set to 'Continue', it's as if the $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' line in the script doesn't take effect.  I enter a first and last name of a user that doesn't exist on either DC by the way.

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential -Credential
$ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - 
ConnectionUri 'serveromitted' -Authentication Kerberos -Credential 
$UserCredential
$dcs = 'dc1','dc2'
$ErrorCount = 0
$firstname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter First Name'
$lastname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Last Name'
$alias = $firstname.substring(0,1).tolower()+$lastname.tolower()
$primarysmtpaddress = $alias+'@domain.com'
import-pssession $ExchangeSession
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'


foreach ($dc in $dcs)
{
    try {
    Get-Recipient -DomainController $dc -Identity $PrimarySmtpAddress -erroraction stop
    }   
catch {
            $MailboxError = $_.Exception.Message
            $MailboxErrorRegex = "^The operation couldn't be performed because object '.*' couldn't be found on '.*'\.$"
            if ($MailboxError -match $MailboxErrorRegex) 
            {
                $ErrorCount++
            }
        }
$ErrorCount
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That got it. Thank you!